# Sharing code between Routes

Tags: ember.js

In order to share code between my different routes (they are mostly the same), I am trying to do the following:

```
/// Base classes (not real routes)

App.RouteMixin = Ember.Mixin.create({
    ...
});

App.BaseIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend(App.RouteMixin, {
    ...
});

/// NODES

App.rNodesMixin = Ember.Mixin.create({
    ...
});

App.NodesIndexRoute = App.BaseIndexRoute.extend(App.rNodesMixin, {
    ...
});

App.NodesShowRoute = App.BaseShowRoute.extend(App.rNodesMixin, {
    ...
});

App.NodesEditRoute = App.BaseEditRoute.extend(App.rNodesMixin, {
    ...
});

App.NodesNewRoute = App.BaseNewRoute.extend(App.rNodesMixin, {
    ...
});

/// AGENTS

App.rNodesMixin = Ember.Mixin.create({
    ...
});

App.AgentsIndexRoute = App.BaseIndexRoute.extend(App.rAgentsMixin, {
    ...
});

App.AgentsShowRoute = App.BaseShowRoute.extend(App.rAgentsMixin, {
    ...
});

App.AgentsEditRoute = App.BaseEditRoute.extend(App.rAgentsMixin, {
    ...
});

App.AgentsNewRoute = App.BaseNewRoute.extend(App.rAgentsMixin, {
    ...
});
```

And suddently I am getting the following errors:

```
Assertion failed: The attempt to linkTo route 'nodes.index' failed. The router did not find 'nodes.index' in its possible routes: 'index'
```

The same pattern has worked for the controllers. Is it not possible to reuse code for the routes, with mixin/extend?

Comment: Did you have created the App.Router.map(function(){ this.route("nodes") }) ?

Comment: Sure, my router configuration has not changed, only the way in which I declare the routes. Previously I was defining each route separately, and now I am `extend`ing from a base class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you have some error in your router mapping.I had just changed the router mapping and works.
Give a look in this [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/HDjqK)

I have used the following configuration:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource("nodes", function(){
        // other routes
    });
    this.resource("agents", function(){
        // other routes
    });
});
```